# Class ApplicationSonataAdminBundle not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to deploy a Sonata project.
But I'm not able to get things working because of this error

> Fatal error: Class 'Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\ApplicationSonataAdminBundle' not found in /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/app/AppKernel.php on line 52

I've red a lot of similar subject but they didn't solve my probleme.

In addition to this, when I make a composer install I have the following error :

> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
>     Fatal error: Class 'Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\ApplicationSonataAdminBu
>     ndle' not found in /home/librairill/librairiedamase.com/app/AppKernel.php o
>     n line 52

EDIT :

Result of php composer.phar show sonata-project/*

```
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.9.0  The missing Symfony Admin G...
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.3.0  Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                     1.0.7  Cache library
sonata-project/classification-bundle     3.1.0  Symfony SonataClassificatio...
sonata-project/comment-bundle            3.0.0  Integrate the FOSCommentBun...
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.2.0  Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           2.2    Symfony SonataDatagridBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.0.2  Doctrine2 behavioral extens...
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.0.5  Symfony Sonata / Integrate ...
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.1.10 Symfony SonataEasyExtendsBu...
sonata-project/ecommerce                 2.0.0  E-Commerce solution provide...
sonata-project/exporter                  1.7.0  Lightweight Exporter library
sonata-project/formatter-bundle          3.0.1  Symfony SonataFormatterBundle
sonata-project/google-authenticator      1.0.2  Library to integrate Google...
sonata-project/intl-bundle               2.2.4  Symfony SonataIntlBundle
sonata-project/jquery-bundle             1.10.2 Symfony SonatajQueryBundle
sonata-project/markitup-bundle           2.1.0  Symfony SonataMarkItUpBundle
sonata-project/media-bundle              3.2.0  Symfony SonataMediaBundle
sonata-project/notification-bundle       3.0.0  Symfony SonataNotificationB...
sonata-project/seo-bundle                2.0.2  Symfony SonataSeoBundle
sonata-project/user-bundle               3.2.0  Symfony SonataUserBundle
```

Result of php composer.phar show symfony/*

```
symfony/monolog-bundle     v3.0.3  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge     v3.2.2  Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu      v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* func...
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu  v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related ...
symfony/polyfill-mbstring  v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php54     v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5....
symfony/polyfill-php55     v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5....
symfony/polyfill-php56     v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5....
symfony/polyfill-php70     v1.3.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7....
symfony/polyfill-util      v1.3.0  Symfony utilities for portability of PHP...
symfony/security-acl       v3.0.0  Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access...
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle v2.4.2  Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony            v2.8.10 The Symfony PHP framework
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to provide us the results of these commands : 

`composer show sonata-project/*`  
`composer show symfony/*`

Comment: @AlexandreT done !

Comment: I don't understand why there is a call to Class 'Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\ApplicationSonataAdminBundle' in your AppKernel.php. Please provide us your AppKernel

Comment: But I think you could comment the line 52 of your AppKernel. SonataAdmin do not need to be "easy-extends" like SonataClassification